# Unity3d c#. onClick.AddListener() некорректно работает

Tags: c#, unity3d

В скрипте есть метод, который перезагружает Canvas. В самом Canvas-e есть объект Button, к которому программно крепится перезагружающий метод.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Trashscript : MonoBehaviour {

   public GameObject Temp;
   private GameObject Active;
   int Counter;

   void Start()
   {
       Menu();
   }

   void Menu()
   {
       Counter++;

       if (Active != null) Destroy(Active);
       Active = Instantiate(Temp);

       GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = Counter.ToString();
       GameObject.Find("Btn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu);
   }
}
```

При загрузке в объекте "Text" появляется "1". После нажатия на "Btn" Canvas перезагружается, но уже без текста в "Text", и "Btn" на нём не работает (при нажатии больше ничего не происходит.

Уже 3-й день не могу понять в чём проблема.

Comment: Вообще должно работать..... но...... какие-нибудь ошибки выдает?

Comment: В том то и прикол, что ошибок нет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вынести кнопку в отдельную переменную. Её инициализировать при старте. И там же добавить слушателя.

А когда объект уничтожается не забыть слушателя снять `RemoveListener`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Trashscript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Temp;
    private GameObject Active;
    int Counter;
    private Button myselfButton;

    void Start() {
        myselfButton = GameObject.Find("Btn").GetComponent<Button>();
        myselfButton.onClick.AddListener(Menu);

        Menu();
    }


    void Menu() {
        Counter++;

        if (Active != null) 
            Destroy(Active);

        Active = Instantiate(Temp);

        GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>().text = Counter.ToString();            
    }


    void Destroy() {
        myselfButton.onClick.RemoveListener(Menu);
    }
}
```

---

**UPD**

Если изначально Canvas-ов на сцене нет и если `GameObject Temp` как раз таки лежит изначально префаб `canvas` и инстанциируется он в `Active`, то значит ошибка банальна: надо вместо поиска на сцене `GameObject.Find(....` просто применять действия как раз к инстанциируемому объекту, который лежит в переменной, т.е.

```
Active.GetComponentInChildren.....
```

В целом код будет такой:

```
public GameObject Temp;
private GameObject Active;
int Counter;

void Start() {
    Menu();
}

void Menu() {
    Counter++;

    if (Active != null) {            
        Destroy(Active);
        Active = null;            
    }

    Active = Instantiate(Temp);

    Active.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Counter.ToString();
    Active.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(this.Menu);
}
```

Кстати, я еще добавил `Active = null;`, т.к. при `Destroy(Active);` объект уничтожится со сцены, но в поле `Active` он все еще останется.

**Замечание!**

Если в генерированном канвасе много кнопок, а не одна, тогда есть другой вариант:

Если расположение кнопок меняться не будет, то можно воспользоваться [GetChild(index)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html), чтобы достать конкретный элемент. Что-то типа

```
Active.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu);
```

либо задать для этих конкретных кнопок свои конкретные имена и просто найти через `Find` но непосредственно объекта `Active`. То есть:

```
Active.transform.Find("MyButtonName").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListene‌​r(Menu);
```

Comment: Изначально Canvas-ов на сцене у меня нет, я пробовал переместить первые 2 строки из Start после Instantiate, но результат остаётся тот-же.

Comment: Тогда стоит показать весь код. т. е. что создает канвас, где, происходит ли там работа и какая. Плюс в данном классе есть ли еще что-то и более подробное описание.... ибо некоторые вещи, вырванные из контекста, ничего не дадут

Comment: На канвасе нет ни единого скрипта, всё что там дружит с кодом - этот скрипт. А скрипт висит на пустом GameObject. Кроме этого в сцене есть ещё камера и EventHandler.

Comment: Вы чего-то не договариваете.........Если изначально Canvas-ов на сцене нет, как вы говорите и.если у вас в `GameObject Temp;` инстанциируется как раз `canvas`, то у вас конструкция вида `GameObject.Find("Text")` уже не должна работать в принципе..... ибо должно будет искаться минимум как `GameObject.Find("Canvas(Clone)/Text")` и `GameObject.Find("/Canvas(Clone)/Btn")`.....и если это и правда канвас, то конечно же он у вас уничтожается `if (Active == null) Destroy(Active);` и далее пересоздается.... уже с чистым текстом....................какая вообще основная мысль того, что вы делаете?

Comment: Спасибо за мысль поиска, возможно причина в нём, хотя замена ("Text") на (Active.name + "/Text") желаемого результата не дала. Мысль моих действий - смена языка с помощью кнопки в главном меню. В скрипте меню текст генерируется из отдельного класса, по нажатию кнопки класс перезагружается, но канвас перезагружается, как вы сказали "с пустым текстом"...

Comment: @Tomas дописал в чем может быть ошибка. Можете пробовать)

Comment: @Tomas А вообще, если вы делаете мультиязычность, то не надо пересодавать всякие панели, элементы управления и прочее. Это слишком накладно. Сделайте папку `localization` например. в которой папки `en`, `ru` и прочие. В каждой папке лежит файл с переводом в формате ключ=значение...  Далее делаете класс с методами локализации и свойство (или `enum`), которое хранит текущий язык. Метод перевод например`void setText(string key) {  }` где на вход подается ключ, а он возвращает перевод, в зависимости от текущего свойства языка.. и все..

Comment: @Tomas . все поля будут содержать обращение к этому методу по ключу....типа `Active.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = Localization.setText("couter") + ":" + counter;`.......... далее в программе в любом удобном месте достаточно изменить язык `Localization.ChangeLanguage('en')` и везде все при этом переведется само.... то есть вместо `Localization.setText("couter")` подставится значение из файла переводов

Comment: Ваш вариант из UPD работает, большое спасибо. Только вот у меня на сцене ещё кнопки есть, а GetComponentInChildren возвращает первую попавшуюся кнопку. Я пробовал предложенный вами выше вариант со свойствами, но он не заработал... Поэтому я и прибегаю к перезагрузке канваса в целом...

Comment: @Tomas если расположение кнопок меняться не будет, то можно воспользоваться [GetChild(index)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)  чтобы достать конкретный элемент.....что-то типа `Active.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu);` ....либо задать для этих конкретных кнопок свои конкретные имена и просто найти через `Find` но непосредственно объекта `Active`. То есть:   `Active.transform.Find("MyButtonName").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(Menu);`

Comment: спасибо ещё раз. С Active.transform.Find("MyButtonName"), теперь всё работает как нужно.